# Use a custom version of clang in Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode

I installed the recent version of clang (to `/usr/local/`). How do I set up Xcode to use this and not the built-in version of clang?

Comment: This should be on StackOverflow as is about development tools

Comment: @Mark as for your own [question](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/xcode-questions) in Meta, the question shouldn't be considered off-topic.

Comment: @Thecafremo - This is not about how to use the windows in Xcode which could be considered OSX use but about how to program with Xcode (also I think this has been answered in SO before)

Comment: @Mark He is asking for a way of *configuring* Xcode, not a way of *developing* with it.

Answer (score 1):

Custom toolchain answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63688639/c20-library-support-for-xcode-12/63690216

1. See the structure of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr` because that's how you'll need to arrange your installation. Also we'll use the `ToolchainInfo.plist` file.
2. Copy the default `xctoolchain` bundle from above, and  paste it into `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains`. In the `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains/my_toolchain.xctoolchain/ToolchainInfo.plist` file, change the identifier to something else.
3. In the `usr` folder, delete the `bin` folder. Go to `/usr/local` and create a alias of the `bin` folder. Move that alias to `usr` folder in the toolchain. Do the same for every other folder. You can also create one single alias to the parent folder of the installation and rename it to `usr` and move it to toolchain file.
4. In `~/.bash_profile`, add a line `export TOOLCHAINS=org.llvm.13.0.0git` or and replace the `org.llvm.13.0.0git` with your identifier.
5. Open Xcode, Xcode menu > Toolchains  > select your toolchain.
6. Every time you build a project, remember to set `Enable index-while-building functionality` to `NO` or you might get a build error.
7. For your custom Clang, you might need to set `export SDKROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk"` or corresponding to your OS in the `~/.bash_profile` too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of my answer on StackOverflow: [How can I force Xcode to use custom compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43355809/598057).

> People say it is possible with custom toolchains. I didn't make a research on them because easier solution worked well for me:
>
> > It is also possible to run frontend plugins directly by setting appropriate "build settings" of Xcode. (Several ways to do this, you can set them on the command line for instance: xcodebuild build FOO=bla.) Here are a few build settings that I found useful to inject C flags:
> >
> > OTHER_CFLAGS, OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS or to replace the compiler(s) and linker(s):
> >
> > CC, CPLUSPLUS, LD, LDPLUSPLUS, LIBTOOL
> >
> > The same approach works to control the "analyze" action: CLANG_ANALYZER_EXEC, CLANG_ANALYZER_OTHER_FLAGS
> >
> > Disclaimer: some of those build settings are undocumented (afaik). Use at your own risk.
>
> (Taken from [[cfe-dev] Compile/refactor iOS Xcode projects](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2014-March/035816.html))
>
> For me it was enough to define the following User-Defined Settings in Build Settings of Xcode projects:
>
> CC=my-c-compiler
>
> CXX=my-cxx-compiler
>
> LIBTOOL=my-linker-for-static-libraries

Comment: You could have copied the formatting too. (click on edit and copy the answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed clang through the homebrew LLVM package, the following works for me with Xcode 14.3. It's at least an alternative to the other answers so far. I don't know whether this is supported by Apple nor whether it's advisable however.

Steps are:

1. Ensure the path `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains` exists:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/Library/Developer/Toolchains
```

2. Symbolically link the toolchains from homebrew's LLVM installation:

```sh
ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/Toolchains/* ~/Library/Developer/Toolchains
```

3. Restart Xcode. "Toolchains" shows up now (if it didn't before) under Xcode's Xcode menu and it has an Xcode option followed by one or more options that begin with "org.llvm".

[image: Xcode menu with Toolchains]

4. Select Xcode -> Toolchains -> org.llvm.16.0.4 (or whichever release of LLVM you have installed through homebrew).
5. If enabled, disable the "Enable Index-While-Building Functionality" build option (`COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE`) from within projects' build settings for projects that are to be built with the new toolchain.

Steps 1 and 2 can alternatively use the `/Library/Developer/Toolchains` path, which is the same as above but without the `~` prefix. This presumably will provide system wide availability of the new toolchains. I have only confirmed that it also worked for me however. Those steps will probably need to be run through `sudo` then to have the privileges necessary for them.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/417985/237?

Comment: @mmmmmm A viewer's impression of the answer you linked (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/417985/237) is that their steps 1, 2, 3, and 4 are different than steps 1 and 2 of my answer, and aren't specific to using homebrew. Additionally, I don't get from their answer, that copying "the default xctoolchain bundle from above... into ~/Library/Developer/Toolchains" may cause Toolchains menu option to appear. When I read that answer, I was like: I have no Toolchains menu option, so how do I even get that? So, my answer also makes clearer IMO how Toolchains appears.